# jQuery slideDown animation jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I notice when I change the padding settings on the **content** class (I think there is too much white space), it completely messes up the smooth dropdown. I'm not sure why this is the case, I can not see anything in the JavaScript.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakeguybrushthreepwood/jhLgZ/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png">TIME</h2></div>
<div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam turpis urna, tristique quis convallis nec, dapibus sed velit.</p></div>
<div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png">CREATIVITY</h2></div>
<div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam turpis urna, tristique quis convallis nec, dapibus sed velit.</p></div>
<div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png">BUDGET</h2></div>
<div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam turpis urna, tristique quis convallis nec, dapibus sed velit.</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.title {
    padding-left:15px;
    height:17px;
    background: transparent url('http://www.elevate1.co.uk/dropdownwitharrows/images/arrow-toggle.png') 0px 5px  
        no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:10px;

}
.title img{
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.title span{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    float: left;
}
.on {
    background: transparent url('http://www.elevate1.co.uk/dropdownwitharrows/images/arrow-toggle.png') 0 -10px  no-repeat;
}
.content {
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.title').click(function() {
        $('.title').removeClass('on');
        $('.content').slideUp('normal');
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Did my solution fix your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is as the container's height is animated, the children of that container are being affected by margins, line-heights, etc, which are all dependent on the boundaries of the container.  Add the following to fix:

```
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Yeah, it's that simple :P

Here's your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhLgZ/5/) updated.

Comment: Sorry @monners, had my first weekend off in quite sometime. Thanks for the update! Did the trick.